# Limit of fixed ratio

Tags: limits

If $a>0,\,b>0$  and we require $p=\dfrac{a}{a+b}$ then it follows that limit as $a+b$ goes to infinity equal $p.$ Then, how can I formally show that for fixed $k>0$, limit of $\dfrac{a+k}{a+k+b}$ also goes to $p$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please ask a question following the rules of the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: which rule did I violate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a+b=x$.

Thus, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x-b}{x}=p,$$ which says
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b}{x}=1-p.$$
Id est, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a+k}{a+k+b}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x-b+k}{k+x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1-\frac{b}{x}+\frac{k}{x}}{\frac{k}{x}+1}=\frac{1-(1-p)+0}{0+1}=p$$

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I find confusing is that as x tends to infinity, then b necessarily tends to infinity too (as the ratio is fixed). Then, writing %\lim_{x\to\infty} (x-b)/x seems weird as b is also involved. Am I unnecessarily worried about this?

Comment: Yes by your given $b\rightarrow\infty$.